# Powershell naming conventions/scoping

Tags: powershell, naming-conventions

I want to create a Powershell function/cmdlet which installs (and one that uninstalls) a web application: copies files, creates an app pool, creates the web application, sets up all kinds of IIS properties, does some web.config modifications, etc. I'm confused about how I should name it. Powershell has this verb-object naming convention, and it's all nice, but the names I want to use (New-WebApplication, etc.) are already taken by the WebAdministration module (which this new function will use internally). Is there a nice way to scope my functions to make it clear that it's a different module? Like mymodule.New-WebApplication, My-New-WebApplication, New-MyWebApplication? Or I could call it Install-WebApplication but that could lead to confusion because of reusing the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this recently for a similar issue. This could have many opinionated answers but this would handle the *way to scope my functions to make it clear that it's a different module*.

You could use the `-Prefix` parameter of `Import-Module`

```
Import-Module mymodule -Prefix Super
```

So when you go to use your cmdlet you would call it with

```
New-SuperWebApplication
```

Alternatively, you can also explicitly call the cmdlet with the module path

```
mymodule\New-WebApplication
```

Comment: I was hoping there's a non-opinionated answer since MS even prescribes the usable verbs, and this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Regarding opinions ... :-)  I prefer the <moduleName>\command approach because the moduleName is always the same (barring the author renaming the module).  If you pick prefix Super and I pick Webby and someone else picks WebManager, it's harder to know which module's commands are being called.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Matt's answer, but I wanted to offer another perspective.

I wrote a module where the intention was specifically to recreate the functionality of an existing cmdlet. I named my function differently, but I also exported functions from the module that allow the caller to overrride the existing cmdlet with mine (using an Alias, which is interpreted first), and then to also undo that process.

This allowed someone to explicitly call the function without needing to use `-Prefix` nor use the `\` syntax, using the new name with new code, but it also allowed one to use my function as a drop-in replacement for existing code by calling a single new command.

Here's that module if you want to take a look:
[DnsCmdletFixes](https://github.com/briantist/DnsCmdletFixes)